# How do 2 devices communicate over an ethernet switch

Tags: ethernet, lan

Before I proceed, I'd like to mention that I did try to research this topic on the internet, but I still need clarification.

Let's say I have two Linux machines connected to a switch (and only to a switch). Machine A has an IP address of 10.0.0.1 and machine B -- 10.0.0.2. I used `nmcli` command to set the IP address and create an ethernet interface for each machine. Everything works as expected.

Now, the confusing part is how machine A can find machine B and vice versa? I'm using the following command to connect from machine A to machine B:

`ssh userB@10.0.0.2`

And it works, even if this is the very first data transmission. This surely means that machine A somehow already knew the machine's B MAC address; otherwise, the frame wouldn't find its way to machine B. But how? Since the IP address is meaningless to the switch (Level2), why when I do `ping 10.0.0.2` or `ssh 10.0.0.2`, it still works?

Comment: How did you not find [arp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) given the rest of the details here?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I did see that arp returns the ip address and MAC of the other machines on the network, but how does it get populated? Does it scan the network when I run ```arp``` or does it do it when it is connected to a LAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the ARP cache was already populated. Maybe there was a [grations ARP](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/Gratuitous_ARP) broadcast:

> Every time an IP interface or link goes up, the driver for that interface will typically send a gratuitous ARP to preload the ARP tables of all other local hosts.

If not, most likely an ARP request/reply was happening right before the first ping. Check the `arp` command or `ip neigh`.

In general I suggest you use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to explore what's going on, or something like `tcpdump -n -i eth0 not ssh` if your are working remotely (note the `-n` to prevent name resolution). You can also record traffic with `tcpdump -s 9999 -w output.pcap` and view it later in Wireshark.

If you sniff network traffic on a third PC, keep in mind that switches will not send traffic to all ports when they have learned where the destination is. Some switches allow you to configure a mirror port to observe all traffic to or from a certain port. Either way you should always be able to observe ARP requests as they are broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

basically, when the first packet reach to the switch ( virtual or physical switch ), the switch will populate arp broadcast packet for the sake of getting all devices mac and ip addresses. so even though ip addresses seem meaningless to switches ( cause they're layer 3 concept but switch is for layer 2 ), switches still need those data to process the packets. because this is how we, as human beings, interact with computers for transmitting data by using ip addresses.
when you ping a device, like 10.0.0.2, the switch will search in it's arp table and find the corresponding mac address and also the interface for reaching to the destination.
the best way to comprehend the whole process is to capture the data using wireshark or even implementing a simple topology in softwares like cisco packet tracer.